# Bootup doesn't follow /etc/fstab

Tags: 15.10, fstab, uuid

Good morning,

I have a media server that has a total of 22 drives. OS, OS Backup and then the media drives. This is Ubuntu 15.10. I have utilized the UUID for setting up the `/etc/fstab` file. When the system reboots it appears that the assignments in the `fstab` file are ignored. My drives are all randomly connected to different directories.

These 4 Primary Drives are my Music, Movies, TV-Shows and Pictures

```
/dev/sdn
/dev/sdq
/dev/sds
/dev/sdt
```

as show in `/etc/fstab`.

But upon reboot, they, along with others, don't match what is in the `/etc/fstab` file.

===============

blkid:

```
/dev/sdn1: LABEL="PICTURES" UUID="1f3a0b93-f7f9-4aaf-8f7a-c66be69b1312" 

/dev/sdq1: LABEL="MOVIES-BACKUP" UUID="eb6fd032-e639-44d9-bc9c-ed0797faf051"

/dev/sds1: LABEL="PICTURE-BACKUP" UUID="9a5a09a8-9358-464a-8d6c-2e4decea2d5d" 

/dev/sdt1: LABEL="DOCUMENT-BACKUP" UUID="14d2f3a3-c6f9-4c95-b538-2ecd2bcb7dde"
```

=====

Snapshot of key drives from `/etc/fstab`

```
 /dev/sds1 TVSHOWS 3TB

UUID=5260aa48-e679-4573-92bb-65c79c089dad /media/mediaserver/TVSHOWS  ext4 defaults 0 0

/dev/sdt1 MOVIES 3TB

UUID=d2cbe3e9-ae46-4e64-8cb8-a852e1102ba5 /media/mediaserver/MOVIES   ext4 defaults 0 0

/dev/sdq1 MUSIC 4TB

UUID=a92f755b-a307-44d2-a5ee-82288e6d471d /media/mediaserver/MUSIC    ext4 defaults 0 0

/dev/sdn1 PICTURES 3TB

UUID=1f3a0b93-f7f9-4aaf-8f7a-c66be69b1312       /media/mediaserver/PICTURES             ext4
```

==================

Snapshot from `mount`

```
/dev/sds1 on /media/mediaserver/TVSHOWS-SPLIT type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdt1 on /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/MUSIC type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdq1 on /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/PICTURES type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdn1 on /media/mediaserver/PICTURES type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

==================

df -h

```
/dev/sde1       1.8T  1.8T     0 100% /media/mediaserver/STANDBY/MUSIC

/dev/sdf1       1.8T  1.1T  683G  61% /media/mediaserver/MOVIES-MASTER

/dev/sdi1       3.6T  7.6G  3.4T   1% /media/mediaserver/MUSIC

/dev/sdg1       2.7T  1.4T  1.3T  53% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/TVSHOWS

/dev/sdk1       2.7T  2.0T  655G  75% /media/mediaserver/STANDBY/PICTURES

/dev/sdn1       2.7T  299G  2.3T  12% /media/mediaserver/PICTURES

/dev/sdl1       2.7T   24G  2.6T   1% /media/mediaserver/DOCUMENTS

/dev/sdm1       2.7T   73M  2.6T   1% /media/mediaserver/STANDBY/SYSTEM-IMAGES

/dev/sdc1       2.7T  1.7T  875G  67% /media/mediaserver/TVSHOWS

/dev/sdd1       2.7T  1.5T  1.1T  57% /media/mediaserver/MOVIES

/dev/sdh1       2.7T   21G  2.6T   1% /media/mediaserver/STANDBY/DOCUMENTS

/dev/sds1       2.7T   73M  2.6T   1% /media/mediaserver/TVSHOWS-SPLIT

/dev/sdv1       2.7T  2.5T  149G  95% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/MOVIES

/dev/sdu1       2.7T  1.7T  939G  65% /media/mediaserver/SYSTEM-IMAGES

/dev/sdb1       459G   70M  435G   1% /media/mediaserver/SYSTEM-SDB-DRV

/dev/sdt1       2.7T   14G  2.6T   1% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/MUSIC

/dev/sdj1       3.6T  1.7T  1.8T  50% /media/mediaserver/STANDBY/TVSHOWS

/dev/sdq1       1.8T  301G  1.5T  18% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/PICTURES

/dev/sdo1       1.8T  276G  1.5T  16% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/DOCUMENTS

/dev/sdr1       1.8T  1.4T  357G  80% /media/mediaserver/BACKUPS/SYSTEM-IMAGES

/dev/sdp1       3.6T  2.5T  973G  73% /media/mediaserver/MOVIES-UPDATE
```

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu 15.10 is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. If they haven't already been removed, the official archives will soon no longer be available, and you won't be able to install any new software on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe the "drive-letters", they could change easily.
Mounting in fstab using UUID is the correct way and you did that already.
You also could mount using partition-labels but you must make sure that every 
partition has a unique label.
The fstab-entries would look like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/DATA  /media/mediaserver/DATA  ext4  defaults  0  0
/dev/disk/by-label/MUSIC  /media/mediaserver/MUSIC  ext4  defaults  0  0
```

This way would be less confusing with your large number of drives.
Open your file-manager and browse to `/dev/disk/by-label` and you will find all your partitions listed by their label. Partitions which are not labeled are not listed in this directory.